# How can I set up mysql logs so that syntax errors are logged?

Tags: mysql, logging, syntax

I've got mysql logging `log_slow_queries` or whatever, and had turned on all query logging for a moment before I found it to just be spammy and thus useless.

How can I log only mysql queries that result in syntax errors?

Comment: You should look at the general log: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Comment: Right, I should have been more clear that I already checked that log out, I was hoping that there was a way to view queries with improper syntax and ignore queries that have the proper syntax.  Because viewing everything in the log is so spammy that it's useless.

Comment: All I can suggest to better filter the queries is to store them in a table instead of a file. I am not sure about a specific error log option in MySQL.